# Como ocultar decimais em pascal?

Tags: matemática, pascal, decimal

Estou fazendo um conversor de moeda e estou tendo problemas com os decimais, por ex: **"$1.0 é igual a R$ 0.18248175182481752"**

Gostaria de saber como ocultar os decimais a partir da segunda casa.

O código é o seguinte:

```
uses crt, Graph;
var valorA, valorB, op:Real;

Procedure dolarToReal;
begin

ClrScr;
WriteLn('Digite o valor em dólares: ');
ReadLn(valorA);

valorB := (valorA * 5.48 );
ClrScr;

WriteLn('R$ ', valorA, ' é igual à $ ', valorB);
readln();


end;


Procedure realToDolar;
begin

ClrScr;
WriteLn('Digite o valor em reais: ');
ReadLn(valorA);

valorB := (valorA / 5.48 );
ClrScr;

WriteLn('$', valorA, ' é igual a R$ ', valorB);
readln();

end;


Procedure menu;
begin


WriteLn('1 - Real > Dólar');
WriteLn('2 - Dólar > Real');
ReadLn(op);

if op = 1 
 then
  begin 
  
  realToDolar
  
  end;
if op = 2 
 then
  begin
  
  dolarToReal
  
  end;



end;

begin
  
  textColor(Black);
  textBackground(White);
  ClrScr;

  menu
  
 
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar :0:2 no resultado final:

```
WriteLn('$', valorA, ' é igual a R$ ', valorB:0:2);
```